# Segmentation fault error .. using opencv_createsamples

Tags: opencv, segmentation-fault, haar-classifier, createsamples

hope you are fine. I was following this tutorial to create my own cascade: https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/ ... when I try to create test samples .. it gives me this error --> Create test samples from single image applying distortions... Segmentation fault (core dumped)
it will be really great if you can help

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the exact same issue while following the tutorial. I was using opencv 3.4.1 contrib version.I solved it by uninstalling opencv and installed it using this command

```
sudo apt install libopencv-dev
```